# MdBootstrap integrated into NuxtJS project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, material-design, nuxt.js, mdbootstrap

I am trying to integrate the material design from https://mdbootstrap.com/vue/ into my NuxtJS project but i failed to find any indication on how to add that to nuxt.

For bootstrap-vue, I added it into my `nuxt.config.js` as it follows :

`modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
  ],`

but it doesn't seem to work for mdbootstrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a nuxt project standing, all you need to do is

`yarn add mdbvue bootstrap-css-only`
OR
`npm install mdbvue bootstrap-css-only`

...then edit your **nuxt.config.js**, so it adds necessary styles and transpiles the library's ES6:

```
  css: [
   'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css',
   'mdbvue/build/css/mdb.css'
  ]
  ...
  build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {},
    transpile: [
      'mdbvue'
    ]
  }
```

and voilà! [Checkout out the official guide](https://mdbootstrap.com/articles/vue/mdb-vue-nuxt-js-quick-start-guide/) for some extra details and start using MDB with Nuxt today!

Best

Comment: I think this one should be marked as the best answer